# Replacing a list element in python

Tags: python, list, replace

The function should return the *text* with the *word* replaced with asterisks.
Not sure why my original code wouldn't work as the logic seems correct to me.

```
text = "this shit is cool"
def censor(text, word):
    lst = text.split()
    ast = ""
    result = ''
    for char in word:
        ast += "*"
    for wrd in lst:
        if wrd == word:
            wrd = ast    #why doesn't this part work??

    print " ".join(lst)

censor(text, "shit")
```

This is my corrected code after I looked up some other related problems. It just seems more complex and unnecessary. Why does this one work instead of my original code?

```
def censor(text, word):
    lst = text.split()
    ast = ""
    result = ''
    for char in word:
        ast += "*"
    for wrd in lst:
        if wrd == word:
            loc = lst.index(word)     #I can't just change it directly? using wrd?
            lst[loc] = ast

    return " ".join(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def censor(text,word):
    return text.replace(word,'*'*(len(word)))
```